# SqliteDatabase.rawQuery(queryStr,null) gives no records but same query executed through DB Browser for SQlite windows app gives records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

SqliteDatabase.rawQuery(queryStr,null) gives no records but same query executed through DB Browser for SQlite windows app gives records

```
String query =
                    "SELECT DISTINCT id_map.from_id, id_map.from_type, item.title, item.short_title,  item.id, item.web_desc, item.piece, item.price, item.retail_price, " +
                    " item.feature_codes, item.dims, item.in_stock, item.stock_stat, item.warranty, item.aspect_code, item.aspect, item.color, item.store_codes, item.room_code " +
                    " FROM id_map, item WHERE id_map.from_id = item.id AND id_map.from_type = 'I' AND id_map.to_id = " + subCategoryId +
                    " ORDER BY id_map.seq ASC";
```

Comment: try removing  id_map. before every field name.

Comment: have you checked if the db is same in app and db browser?

Comment: Show the actual value of `query`. Also show the exact query you're executing in DB Browser.

Comment: @Anurag: id_map is table name so it's required to refer a table

Comment: @Junaid: Yes,I executed the db file is exactlly same ,no doubt.

Comment: @CL                                                                                            SELECT DISTINCT id_map.from_id, id_map.from_type, item.title, item.short_title,  item.id, item.web_desc, item.piece, item.price, item.retail_price,item.feature_codes, item.dims, item.in_stock, item.stock_stat, item.warranty, item.aspect_code, item.aspect, item.color, item.store_codes, item.room_code FROM id_map, item WHERE id_map.from_id = item.id AND id_map.from_type = 'I' AND id_map.to_id = 122 ORDER BY id_map.seq ASC;

Comment: Show both. And to edit the question, click "edit".

Comment: @CL: Did not get it. What both?

Comment: Hi Guys, I discovered the root cause, able to resolve the issue.Thanks for your feedback.